# Calendar in Odoo Website V10

Tags: odoo-website

I'm trying to display  calendar in Odoo website
Please find my below code:

**website_calendar_templates.xml**

```
 <template id="website_calendar_assets_frontend" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend" name="Calendar block assets">
<xpath expr="." position="inside">      
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/website_calendar/static/lib/date/js/date.js"></script>          
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/website_calendar/static/src/js/website_calendar_block.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/website_calendar/static/lib/fullcalendar/js/fullcalendar.js"></script>
 </xpath>
 </template>
<template id="index" name="calendar">  
<t t-call="website.layout"> 
<div id="wrap">    
<div class="oe_structure"/>    
<div class="container"> 
<div class="calendar">
</div></div><div class="oe_structure"/></div> 
</t>
</template>
```

**website_calendar_block.js**

```
 (function () {//odoo.define('website_calendar.website', function(require) {//"use strict";
'use strict';
var website = openerp.website;
var _t = openerp._t;
website.ready().then(function () {        website.if_dom_contains('div.calendar', function ($el) {            var $calendar = $el.find('.calendar');
}());
```

**main.py:**

```
 class WebsiteCalendarController(http.Controller):
       @http.route(['/calendar'],  type='http', auth="public",          website=True)  

def calendar(self ,page=1, **searches):                  
 #return request.redirect("website_calendar.index",values)   
return request.render('website_calendar.index', {'values': [""]})
```

I have added Calendar in Top Menu . when click on calendar In my website page it render the page but doesn't display  calendar in website
can anyone please help me to resolve it .